# How to convert a value from a drop down list into a date type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, converters

I have a three Drop down lists , Day , Month, and year , after I put them into a string how do I convert them into a Date Time, knowing that I'll store this date in a database`

```
string DOBDay   = DDLDay.SelectedValue;
string DOBMonth = DDLMonth.SelectedValue;
string DOBYear  = DDLYear.SelectedValue;
string date     =  DOBDay + DOBMonth + DOBYear;
```

Comment: use Convert.ToDateTime(stringvalue)

Comment: use [Convert.ToDateTime(date)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

Comment: you should add separators in your datestring first so that your date string looks like DOBDay/DOBMonth/DOBYear.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
Date myDate = new Date(Convert.ToInt32(DDLYear.SelectedValue),
                       Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonth.SelectedValue),
                       Convert.ToInt32(DDLDay.SelectedValue));
```